# I am able to pair my Android phone through bluetooth in RPI but I couldn't able to connect through it

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth, raspi-config

I Started using raspberry pi recently,when I tried to connect my phone through bluetooth with an created agent by using this command `bluetoothctl -a`. I got this error

`Err : a2dp-source profile connect failed`

When I tried to connect through RFCOMM with the command

```
$sudo rfcomm connect /dev/rfcomm<BDADDR>
```

I got the following error
`Err: Can't connect RFCOMM Socket : Connection refused`

Comment: Even I am facing similar issue.. Any help is really appreciated... Thanks,
Jeeva